# How to get the top row for each group in a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

I'm working with a large data set that contains information on Netflix movies and tv shows, including the rating, title, type, and release year. I narrowed the dataset down to movies/tv shows released only in the US. I want to run a query that will return each year and the rating that had the most releases in that given year. Currently, my query is returning each rating for every year.

The dataset can be found here: [Netflix dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows)

I was able to run this query:

SELECT release_year, rating, type, COUNT(rating) AS rating_amount
FROM netflix_condense
WHERE country = 'United States'
GROUP BY release_year, rating, type
ORDER BY release_year DESC, COUNT(rating) DESC;

which returned:

[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dByd.png).

However, I am only interested in the first row for every year. I tried to use LIMIT but that only returned the first row for 2021, and the years go back to 1942. I know that MAX(COUNT(rating)) does not work in MySQL. I'm sort of new to MySQL and would like any advice on how to acheive this or where to go from here. Much appreciation!

Comment: If first place is shared with multiple rows, what then? Pick just one, or return all?

Comment: @SimonGoater I would like to return all. So for example: 2021 TV-MA TV Show 38 followed by 2020 TV-MA TV-Show 81, instead of listing all the ratings and rating_amount for each year. Does that make more sense?